# Defining a new keyword in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I'm trying to define a new keyword for my algorithm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\SetKw{kwInit}{Init:}
\begin{algorithm}
\kwInit{$\alpha_n=1$ for all $n$}
\While{not at end of this document}{
do this and that
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The problem is the colon after Init is not automatically generated and I have to define it like this {Init:} which will generate a bold colon instead of a normal one. How to fix this?
Also, the argument "for all n" will be italic and immediately followed by "while" of the next line. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you are after `\SetKwInput`, with syntax

```
\SetKwInput{<name>}{<keymord>}
```

which defines the macro `\<name>{<arg>}` to print `<keyword>` in keyword typography followed by `:`, and then argument `<arg>`.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwInput{kwInit}{Init}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\kwInit{$\alpha_n=1$ for all $n$}
\While{not at end of this document}{
do this and that
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]