# Trying to write `loop`keyword in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I'm using **algorithm2e** and I need to use the `loop`keyword as it appears here:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

MWE

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}



%%% Coloring the comment as blue
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}                % Set the Input
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}              % set the Output


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
  
  \KwInput{Your Input}
  \KwOutput{Your output}
  \KwData{Testing set $x$}
  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} := 0$ \tcp*{this is a comment}
  \tcc{Now this is an if...else conditional loop}
  \If{Condition 1}
    {
        Do something    \tcp*{this is another comment}
        \If{sub-Condition}
        {Do a lot}
    }
    \ElseIf{Condition 2}
    {
        Do Otherwise \;
        \tcc{Now this is a for loop}
        \For{sequence}    
        { 
            loop instructions
        }
    }
    \Else
    {
        Do the rest
    }
    
    \tcc{Now this is a While loop}
   \While{Condition}
   {
        Do something\;
   }

\caption{Example code}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213502/31034

Comment: Thank you. I tried what's on that page before but it actually takes the new keyword as a word and not as a loop with its block.

Comment: If you use `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` packages, you can use `\Loop <text> \EndLoop` as a loop block.

Comment: Your screenshot is not complete, it does not show how the loop ends.

Comment: @AndréC Updated. Check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am now discovering this package and in the documentation, there are macros that allow you to define your own keywords.

There are some that define loops, but they add the stop test either at the end or at the beginning of the loop.

So I opted for the macro that defines a block, since the stop test is given before the end of the loop. `\SetKwBlock{Loop}{Loop}{end}`

The first parameter defines the name of the macro, so if you write it with a capital letter `{Loop}`, you must do the same when calling: `\Loop`. If you write it with a lower case `{loop}`, you must call `\loop`. The second parameter is how the keyword will be displayed in the algorithm.

I quote the manual on page 35:

> **\SetKwBlock{Begin}{begin}{end}** defines a macro **\Begin{txt}** which
>   denotes a block. The text is surrounded by the words *begin* and *end* in
>   keyword typography and shifted to the right (indented). In **\Vline** *or*
>   **\Line** *mode* a straight vertical line is added. **\Begin(side
>   text){text}** gives also text in a block surrounded by *begin* and *end*,
>   but *side text* if put after the *begin* keyword. Combined with **\tcc*[f]**
>   macro, it allows you to put comments on the same line as *begin*. You
>   can also use alternativ **\uBegin{txt}** which acts as **\Begin{txt}** but
>   without *end*. Useful for example as a part separator that doesn't
>   necessary need an *end* keyword.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,boxruled,ruled,noline]{algorithm2e}



%%% Coloring the comment as blue
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}                % Set the Input
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}              % set the Output
\SetKwBlock{Loop}{Loop}{end}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon

  \KwInput{Your Input}
  \KwOutput{Your output}
  \KwData{Testing set $x$}
  \Loop ( until the terminal condition is met. One epoch:)
  {n=n+1

  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} := 0$ \tcp*{this is a comment}
  \tcc{Now this is an if...else conditional loop}
  \If{Condition 1}
    {
        Do something    \tcp*{this is another comment}
        \If{sub-Condition}
        {Do a lot}
    }

   terminal condition: RMSE on \dots
}
\caption{Example code}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Flawless! Thank you very much, Andre!!!

Comment: The `Loop` keyword should be in Upper or Lower case?

Comment: I just add more explnations, is it clear now?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for such a great answer